# In a PowerShell script using 1passsword cli, how can I automate the login with no user action, filling in the password automatically

Tags: windows, powershell, 1password

I'm working on a PowerShell script with the 1Password CLIv2. I need it to login automatically.

The command I'm using is:

```
Invoke-Expression $(op signin)
```

Right now it stops here:

```
PS C:\Users\MyDirectory\Downloads> .\Test.ps1
Enter the password for my@email.com at domain.1password.com:
```

I need to throw in the password automatically and let the script continue.

Comment: You need to capture it upfront securely store and use it. There are lots of StackOverflow Q&A's, blogs, articles Youtube videos showing how.

Comment: I have the password hard coded. I just need to know how to put it in that password prompt automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I came across something that cleared this up.
Make one script file (test.ps1) containing this:

***$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;***

***$wshell.AppActivate('Your Title')***

***Sleep 4***

***$wshell.SendKeys('password1234')***

***$wshell.SendKeys('~')***

Then make another script file(test2.ps1) containing whatever you need the password for and whatever you want to accomplish:

***Invoke-Expression $(op signin)***

Then put this into the PS prompt:

***.\Test.ps1; .\Test2.ps1***

And Bob's your uncle, you're done.

Comment: Yep, this will work but note that ***storing credentials in plain text in a script is not the best security practice*** and can/will lead to risk issues if discovered by your security team or other less-than-trustworthy types. Use  [***PS secrets manager***](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+secrets+manager%27&t=h_&ia=web) instead and call them from there, or the [***Windows Credential Store***](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+windows+credential+store%27&t=h_&ia=web)